# QtQuick2 does not find .h files with new classes

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2

I'm trying to learn how to connect Qt quick object signals to slots in classes in the c++ code. When I add the class definitions to the "qtquick2applicationviewer.h" file that is created by the system, everything works.
But I can't find a way to add my own .h file (I should do this as indicated in the .h file: "It is recommended not to modify this file, since newer versions of Qt Creator may offer an updated version of it.")
I tried adding the source to the .pro file (HEADERS += classes.h), also tried to add it to the .pri file (HEADERS += $$PWD/../classes.h) but no luck.

The Error I get is a linker error:
LNK2001: unresolved external sybol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall MyClass::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@Myclass@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
and two more similar.

Any inputs on what I'm doing wrong is highly appreciated :)
Can probably help many others as well as it is a general question bases on the QTQuick tutorial application.

```
//classes.h
#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QVariant>
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject *QMLObject) : m_QMLObject(QMLObject) {}

public slots:
    void handleClick() {
        m_QMLObject->setProperty("text", "Qt was here");
    }


protected:
    QObject *m_QMLObject;
};
#endif // CLASSES_H

//main.cpp
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include "classes.h"
#include <QtQuick>
#include <QtDebug>

void MyClassInQtQhfile::cppSlot(const QString &msg) {
    qDebug() << "Called the C++ slot with message:" << msg;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QTextStream out(stdout);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/Transitions/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();
    QObject *rectangle = viewer.rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("rectangle");
    QObject *text = viewer.rootObject()->findChild<QObject*>("text");
    MyClassInQtQhfile *myClassInQtQhfile = new MyClassInQtQhfile();
    MyClass *myclass = new MyClass(text);
    QObject::connect(rectangle, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                     myClassInQtQhfile, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));
    QObject::connect(rectangle, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)),
                     myclass, SLOT(handleClick()));
    //rectangle is the object name, which needs to be define in qml for the component.e.g. objectName: "rectangle"

    return app.exec();
}

//QML object sending signal
Rectangle {
                objectName: "rectangle"
                id: bottomLeftRect
                width: 64
                height: 64
                color: "#00000000"
                radius: 6
                anchors.left: parent.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                anchors.bottomMargin: 20
                border.color: "#808080"
                signal qmlSignal(string msg)
                MouseArea {
                    id: mousearea3
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked:{
                        bottomLeftRect.qmlSignal("Hello from QML")
                        onClicked: page.state = 'State2'
                    }
                }
            }
```

Beginning of qtquick2applicationviewer.pri

```
# checksum 0x21c9 version 0x90005
# This file was generated by the Qt Quick 2 Application wizard of Qt Creator.
# The code below adds the QtQuick2ApplicationViewer to the project and handles
# the activation of QML debugging.
# It is recommended not to modify this file, since newer versions of Qt Creator
# may offer an updated version of it.

QT += qml quick

SOURCES += $$PWD/qtquick2applicationviewer.cpp
HEADERS += $$PWD/qtquick2applicationviewer.h
HEADERS += $$PWD/../classes.h
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
...
```

.pro file

```
# Add more folders to ship with the application, here
folder_01.source = qml/Transitions
folder_01.target = qml
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS = folder_01

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# The .cpp file which was generated for your project. Feel free to hack it.
SOURCES += main.cpp

# Installation path
# target.path =

# Please do not modify the following two lines. Required for deployment.
include(qtquick2applicationviewer/qtquick2applicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()

HEADERS += \
    classes.h
```

Comment: First remove your header from qtquick2applicationviewer.pri
Clean workspace and rerun qmake, build and check if moc_classes.cpp was generated.

Comment: removed the header from *.pri, ran qmake and built the project - it worked. no moc_classes.cpp was generated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well moc_classes.cpp had to be generated in build directory, so you miss it. It contains the definition of `MyClass::metaObject` function.